# write python object to a text file line by line

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python object as below:

```
a = """ab: 123
cd: 345
ab: 234
cd: 123
lm:345"""
print(a)

ab: 123
cd: 345
ab: 234
cd: 123
lm:345
```

I want to write it to a text file as it is line by line(my output .txt file should look exactly like the output of print(a))

I tried the below code:

```
outF = open("ab.txt", "w")
for line in a:
  # write line to output file
  outF.write(line)
  outF.write("\n")
outF.close()
```

The ouput of above code looks like this in the output text file:

```
a
b
:

1
2
3


c
d
:

3
4
5


a
b
:

2
3
4


c
d
:

1
2
3


l
m
:
3
4
5
```

The expected output in the below format:

```
ab: 123
cd: 345
ab: 234
cd: 123
lm:345
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate through your string. Just write `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of ‘a’ here is not an object it is a string

"""ab: 123
cd: 345
ab: 234
cd: 123
lm:345"""

If you really want to get the string “line-by-line” do:

```
for line in a.split(“\n”):
   ... rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your case**

a is `string` so python will iterate on it character by character so better convert it into `list` using `split` method.

`split` the string on new line character `\n`

```
a = """ab: 123
cd: 345
ab: 234
cd: 123
lm:345"""

b = a.split("\n")
print(b)

with open("test.txt","w") as f:
  for line in b:
    f.write(line)
    f.write("\n")
```

**Alternative**

As you have to write string as it is you just need

```
with open("test1.txt","w") as f:
  f.write(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could simply be as simple as,

```
with open('test_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(a)
```